# Interested in the future of "Help" for this site?

Tags: discussion, help-center

There's a post at [Introducing a brand new, consolidated, Help Center](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/182812/195988) which discusses changes that are coming to the way Help/FAQ etc. are handled -- go over there and take a look, and make your views known if you wish.

Comment: Are these "userxxx" accounts deleted accounts?